# Continuous Webjob Restarts automatically

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a continuous running web job which starts long running process on a background thread. I have enabled Application logging to write all the logs into a storage table.

Sometimes the web job automatically restarts for no apparent reason and nothing is logged in the storage table. Below is the log information from the storage table

[image: Screen Capture of my log]

I assume whenever the web job stops it should write into the logs (first line in the below screen capture).

[image]

I looked at the memory and CPU consumption of the web app and it was always below 50% during the entire month.

I am using "**Basic**" pricing tier for the web app and set the "**Always On**" to **true**.

How to find out what is the reason behind the web job shutting down? Is there any other place where I can look for more detailed log?

**EDIT** Below is the logs from the scm site which still does not say why it stopped :(

[image]

**EDIT 2** In the log I found some more information.

```
Could not send heartbeat. Access to the path 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\MyWebApp\VirtualDirectory0\data\DaaS\Heartbeats\RD000D3A702E55' is denied.
  at DaaSRunner.Program.Main(String[] args)
  at DaaSRunner.Program.StartSessionRunner()
  at DaaS.HeartBeats.HeartBeatController.<GetHeartBeats>d__8.MoveNext()
  at DaaS.HeartBeats.HeartBeatController.GetNumberOfLiveInstances()
  at DaaSRunner.Program.SendHeartBeat()
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
  at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
  at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
  at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
  at DaaS.HeartBeats.HeartBeat.OpenHeartBeat(String heartBeatPath)
```

Any help?

Comment: Edit 2 is a red herring. That's a log outputted by the DaaS site extension for when two different instances of the same site try to write to the same file.  The second one to try to get the write lock will get access denied since the first instance currently holds the handle.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the WebJob's log file for system logs.

You can get to it by going to the WebJobs dashboard - `https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs`

Comment: I checked the log even under scm but still it did not provide any insight.

Comment: Do you have another instance of this issue? other than the one provided

Comment: I have one instance each on development and testing web apps which are running fine. Does it mean that this might be a once off issue?

Comment: Yes, the VM might have restarted abruptly. Usually shutdowns are graceful and you would see logs for them.

Comment: I will keep a check and if I encounter the issue I will report back. Thanks :)